# How to describe an object with an arbitrary number of properties of same type in JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Is it possible in JsDoc to describe an object with an unknown number of properties having all the same type? In other words, the object is very similar to an array, but the elements are not indexed by a number but by the their name.

I know I can do the following

```
/**
 * @typedef {Object} MyType
 * @summary Description follows here
 * @property {MySubType} propertyA
 * @property {MySubType} propertyB
 * @property {MySubType} propertyC
 */
```

The problem: This describes an type with exactly three properties.

```
/**
 * @typedef {MySubType[]} MyType
 * @summary Description follows here
 */
```

The problem: Here the index is a number.

What I need is the "hybrid": An object-style array or however you want to call it.